# Broken packages and how to deal with them

Tags: 14.04, package-management, aptitude

After installing Xmind software I got recommendation with removing packages. What kind of problem is it and what is general way of solving it and how to deal in current situation?

aptitude output:

[image]

apt-get check gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xmind : Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 but it is not installed
         Depends: lame but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: What kind of software is that screenshot from? I am not familiar with that. Might you please use `apt-get`?

Comment: I have updated question body with apt-get output

Answer (score 1):

As the `apt-get check` output suggested, please run

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That should automatically install all required packages to fix unmet dependencies.